# How can I manipulate ggplot2's fill and color features to generate an automatic legend to a layer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have seen other similar questions and their answers; I haven't been able to deduce an answer from them. Hence, this question.

The data is organized in a way that I thought it'd allow me to have legends automatically added, i.e., *tidy data*. A reproducible example is shown below.

```
#Create Fake Data
set.seed(2019)
myDf = data.frame(time = rep(seq(1,5),2), 
                  smax = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 10,sd = 2),
                  mean = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 5, sd = .8),
                  smin  = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = .001),
                  obser= rep(rnorm(n = 5, mean = 5, sd = 2),2),
                  type = rep(x = c(1,2),each = 5))
myDf[,6] = as.factor(myDf[,6])
.........................................................................
```

As you can see, it's a simple data frame with 6 columns. You can think of this data frame as the result of some data wrangling. For example, `time` is the same for the two types (variable `type`). The `obser` variable is also the same for both types (1 and 2).

**My goal is** to plot a plot graph where I'll use `smin`and `smax`as the limits for my `geom_ribbon`. Furthermore, I want to plot the variable `mean`as a line. For these two layers, I'll have both `fil`and `color`as a way to distinguish these objects by their `type`.

The **problem** arises with my `geom_line` for the `obser` variable. The values for this variable are the same for both types, therefore, there's no reason to apply `color`to them. I'd like them printed in black (and also dashed, but not a necessity).

Here's the code I wrote to achieve this goal:

```
# Plot data using ggplot2
myDf %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x = time, fill = factor(type))) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = smin, ymax = smax), alpha = .25 ) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = mean, color = factor(type)), size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = obser), linetype = 2, size = .8) + 
  labs(x = "Time", y = "") +   
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = .25)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#542788","#b35806","#000000"),
                     labels = c("Model A","Model B","Observed Value")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#542788","#b35806"),
                    labels = c("Model A","Model B"))+    
  theme(legend.position = "bottom" , legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

With this piece of code, I managed to:

1. Plot both regions with `geom_ribbon`satisfactorily.
2. Have legends for both the regions and the lines from the `mean`variable.
3. Plot the `obser`variable as a black, dashed line.

One could argue the code could be improved, and I will accept pointers gladly. For instance, I needed to change the name of my factors in my legend, and I think I should have used `mutate`but I couldn't accomplish what I tried to do. However, what I need now is to add a legend to the `obser` line in which it's written "Observed Values".

*How could I do that, preferably in an automatic way?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force additional color legend values by specifying a fixed label, here I used "observ". As I don't want to split the fill and the color legend, I specified this also for the fill aesthetic, but used "transparent" for the color and not show a filling background:

```
ggplot(myDf, aes( x = time)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = smin, ymax = smax, fill = factor(type)), alpha = .25 ) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = mean, color = factor(type)), size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = obser, color = "observ", fill = "observ"), linetype = 2, size = .8) + 
  labs(x = "Time", y = "") +   
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = .25)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "#542788", "2" = "#b35806","observ" = "#000000"),
                     labels = c("Model A","Model B","Observed Value")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "#542788", "2" = "#b35806","observ" = "transparent"),
                    labels = c("Model A","Model B","Observed Value")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom" , legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

It gives `Warning:Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill`, because `geom_line` is not using the fill aesthetics.

Using a fixed value ("observ") instead of a column (like `type`) inside of the aesthetics, creates a new class of color for this one value. Without specifying a manuall legend, this would result in a different color than black, which often leads to confusing moments, like this one:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1))) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y, color = "green")) +
  geom_hline(aes(color = "black", yintercept = 0.5))
```

[image]

With the named vector inside the `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` the colors are exactly mapped to the specific names. This is helpful, when you don't know in which order they will appear.

Comment: Hey, thanks! This is a clever workaround. Have you faced this situation before? Is the use of "transparent" in situations like this common? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Also, I'm sort of a ggplot2 neophyte and still haven't gotten the gist of using a string in a mapping like ```fill```or ```color```. What's the intent of this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say whether this is a common use of "transparent", but I think I have seen something similar before. Adding color legends like I did comes up here and there, but I usually try to transform my data.

Comment: @MasonBeau I added more explanation.